# How to change the glossary header style?

Tags: glossaries

I would like to change the appearance of the glossary header so that it looks like a table header (meaning it gets a line above an below) and is aligned with the glossaries below. How can i achieve that?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}


\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*\entryname{Name}
\renewcommand*\descriptionname{Bedeutung}
\setglossarystyle{long3colheader}


\newglossaryentry{AT}
{
        name=Außentemperatur,
        description={gemessene Außentemperatur}
}

\newglossaryentry{ALT}
{
        name=Auslegungstemperatur,
        description={die minimale Außentemperatur, bei der die Heizlast des Gebäudes  100\% gedeckt ist}
}


\begin{document}

\clearpage
\printglossaries

\newpage


 \gls{AT} 
 \gls{ALT} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you still want a page break automatically inserted (following the normal mechanism of `\chapter*`) so that `\glossarysection[toc title]{title}` is essentially a custom unnumbered chapter style?

Comment: yes, that would be great. For me is the glossary indeed something like a chapter. merci in advance A